# Open Source Robotic Saw

Tags: tools

I know that there are several opensource printers, i.e. [RepRap](http://reprap.org). Are there any similar projects for robotic woodworking saw or other instruments?

Comment: What kind of saw?  There are plenty of homemade table saws and band saws on YouTube, though I don't know how many of them qualify as open source.  To me, the word "free" is more applicable to the design of a non-software item, such as a woodworking tool, since there is no source code hidden anywhere and the design is based off plans.

Comment: This reads like a request for plans or at minimum asking for an external resource which is off topic. Nothing is stopping your from asking in chat though.

Comment: @grfrazee I rather new to wood working, but I'm guessing what I really want right now is a band saw or keyhole saw, where I could cut a panel into or shape or maybe ever cut portions out of the panel.

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for are CNC routers rather than saws. They're often used to cut complex shapes into or through sheets of material.

Comment: I think I need bot @Jonah, but really the bandsaw as I would like to cut some sheet in the shape for a dog house and other projects. But thanks, I've never heard of a CNC router.

Comment: If you are asking about CNC routing [XCarve](https://www.inventables.com/technologies/x-carve) springs to mind. There are a few projects on Kickstarter and the like.

Comment: I think the question is interesting in this Q&A and should be a SE-wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there are many common computer controlled saws except for custom-built, highly specific machines.

However, there are three common machines that are more general purpose that can probably do the job you need:

- Computer controlled routers
- Computer controlled laser cutters
- Computer controlled high-pressure waterjet cutters.

There are many open source and custom built, as well as commercial CNC routers. As for the other two, I think those remain mostly commercially built.

There are also many companies that operate these machines that will cut things for you, for a fee.

Comment: Note that there are CNC router kits as large as (and functioning like) panel saws, which would make them a fairly reasonable equivalent for your "bandsaw" needs if the stock is fairly flt (or can be built up feom flat pieces).A friend was considering investing in one of those; I'm not sure whether he ever gotnenough interested parties together to justify it.

Comment: I'll also note that a low-budget homebrew was published about six months ago which is  router with a side-cutting bit, hanging against an almost-vertical plywood workpiece from two strings which can be wound/unwound via stepper motors to move it across the surface of that sheet. It doesn't have any z-axis control so you have to manually start and stop each cut, and its accuracy is relatively low, but if your goal is mass-producing plywood cutouts that don't have to be too exact it's the cheapest solution I've yet seen.